# capacitive touch film or integerated capacitive touch panel display? using under glass

Tags: lcd, touchscreen, capacitive, touch-panel

We need to put display under 2mm glass. Our device must have capacitive touch input.
which method should we use? Capacitive Touch Films (place it under glass) or LCDs with integrated capacitive touch (place it exactly under glass)?
For Capacitive touch film i mean something like this:
http://www.buydisplay.com/default/3-2-inch-capacitive-touch-panel-wiith-controller-ft6236-for-240x320-dots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the specific LCD you use, you may find that it will have a layer of glass on the front of the assembly. Adding a further 2mm of glass may push the touch screen over the maximum sensing distance. LCDs with integrated touch panels may or may not be designed to work like this, so it would depend on the model you choose. I have seen datasheets that specify a range of lens thickness that they will work with.

If you use a touch film, you may have more luck. Although I can't see any spec. for touch distance on the one linked. Ideally, you would find that out before committing.